# RoundUP function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, rounding

I want to write code which can round up a set of data and then print it to 3 decimal places. I know that I need to use Ceil function but don't know how to write the correct code. What my code prints is 1 and 2 only! For example for number 1.2345 rounds up to 2.000. I would like to round the number to be 1.235 using ceil function.

My code is:

```
row = 1;
col = 1;
HIGH_ERROR = 2.5;
LOW_ERROR = 0.0;
% Read the file
rawData = dlmread('data_1.csv',',');
% Get the size
[MAX_ROWS, MAX_COLS] = size(rawData);
errorMap = double(zeros(MAX_ROWS, MAX_COLS));
value = ceil(rawData(row, col)*1000/1000);
%Print the raw data
fprintf('Raw Data\n');
for row = 1 : MAX_ROWS
for col = 1 : MAX_COLS
    fprintf('%0.3f ', rawData(row, col));
end
fprintf('\n');
end 
%Print the Error Map
fprintf('Error Map\n');
for row = 1 : MAX_ROWS
for col = 1 : MAX_COLS
    if rawData(row, col) > HIGH_ERROR
        errorMap(row, col) = rawData(row, col);
        rawData(row, col) = HIGH_ERROR;
        if rawData(row, col) < LOW_ERROR
        errorMap(row, col) = rawData(row, col);
        rawData(row, col) = LOW_ERROR;   
        end
    end
fprintf('%0.3f ', errorMap(row, col));
end
fprintf('\n');
end
%Print the Rounded Data
fprintf('Rounded Data\n');
for row = 1 : MAX_ROWS
for col = 1 : MAX_COLS
    value = ceil(rawData(row, col)*1000/1000);
    fprintf('%0.3f ', value);
end
fprintf('\n');
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want

```
value = ceil(rawData(row, col)*1000)/1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

A nice trick which should work on any language which has `round()` would be:

Round Up (Ceil) -> `ceil(x) = round(x + 0.5)`.

Round Down (Floor) -> `floor(x) = round(x - 0.5)`.